# Compile js files twig

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, caching, twig

I'm trying to add some new js files in public/js but when I change my project to prod these files doesn't update in front-end, I already tried to delete the folder /var/cache but nothing change.
When I change the twig file these works fine, but nothing happens with js and css files.

Comment: try to remove the cache of browser , if it works you can work with assets Versioning

Comment: Yes, try cmd/ctrl + shift + r → to hard reload.
Do you use any js/css bundlers like `webpack` (probably symfony/encore) ?